# Dynamic Url through Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the following script :

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/load_data",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(people) {               
                    waiting_list=$('#waiting_list').empty();

                    $.each(people, function(i, waiting){                    
                    waiting_list.append('<a href="profile/details">'+waiting.id+" "+waiting.lname+" "+waiting.sname+'</a>');
                    });
                },
                error: function(data) {
                  //  alert('An error occured, kindly try later');
                }
            });
        }, 10000);


    });
</script>
```

I want to create a dynamic url by adding a variable (id) at the end of the link to be href="profile/details/id .  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
waiting_list.append('<a href="profile/details/'+waiting.id+'">'+waiting.id+" "+waiting.lname+" "+waiting.sname+'</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Append `waiting.id` in `href` like **href="profile/details/'+waiting.id+'"**

**Code,**

```
success: function(people) {               
           waiting_list=$('#waiting_list').empty();
           $.each(people, function(i, waiting){     
               id=waiting.id;
               lname=waiting.lname;
               sname=waiting.sname;
               waiting_list.append('<a href="profile/details/'+id+'">'+id+" "+lname+" "+sname+'</a>');
                              // Append id here ---------------^---------
           });
},
```